# Java.lang.outofmemory error while performing sqlite database operation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, out-of-memory

After storing data into sqlite database i need to retrieving that data and display.
so for that i did like this.

```
private void display() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try{
        cursor2=database.query("patienttestdetails", new String[]{"date","sugarlevel"}, "pid="+patientId+"", null, null, null, "ptdid desc", "2");
        if(cursor2.getCount()==0)
            Toast.makeText(BloodsugarActivity.this, "Add Your Bloodsugar Details To See Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
        {            
            while(cursor2.moveToFirst())
            {
                bloodsugardetails=new TextView(this);
                bloodsugardetails.setText(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("date"))+"  "+cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("sugarlevel")));
                bloodsugardetails.setTextSize(20);
                bloodsugardetails.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_view);
                bloodsugardetails.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);

                layout.addView(bloodsugardetails);
            }
        } 
        cursor2.close();
        database.close();
     }
     catch(Exception exception)
     {}
        }
```

My date base query is like this:

```
   database.execSQL("create table if not exists patienttestdetails(ptdid integer primary key autoincrement,pid integer,date text,sugarlevel interger, FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES patientdetails(id))");
```

My database inserting is fine i checked the database. But while display, i am getting  Java.lang.outofmemory error. My application have lot of XML files and lot of database operations. Before that all are fine i don't know why i am getting this error?

Logcat details:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obZUdicVdDRWlKWXc/edit?usp=sharing

All advices are accepted

Thank you

SHANKAR

Comment: could you plz provide logcat

Comment: Hi Ritesh Gune I don't have option to uplod a photo. please find this like https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obZUdicVdDRWlKWXc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop there. Cursor.moveToFirst returns true if cursor has records (and yours apparently does).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Change it to moveToNext()

**EDIT**: On a side note, doing DB access and UI update in the same thread (UI thread) is not recommended.